# Intuition behind subspace $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $D \subseteq X$. The subspace $\sigma$-Algebra of subsets of $D$, $$σ_D = \{E \cap D : E \in \Sigma\}$$
What is the intuition behind this definition? What is it trying to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's analogous to the subspace topology. It turns out that this definition
gives a very "natural" definition of $\Sigma$ restricted to $D$. The definition is the right one for *the structure induced by $\Sigma$ on $D\subseteq X$*. Here are a couple of reasons why.

---

If $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a topology $\tau$ on a space $X$, and $D\subseteq X$, then the set $\Sigma_D$ as you define it is equal to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the subspace topology $\tau_D$ on $D$. The open sets of $\tau_D$ are exactly the sets $U\cap D$ for $U\in\tau$.

---

The subspace topology on $D$ has another description: it's the smallest topology on $D$ such that the inclusion $D \hookrightarrow X$ is continuous. Similarly, it's not hard to see that

> $\Sigma_D$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $D$ such that the inclusion $i_D\colon D \hookrightarrow X$ is *measurable* — that is,  $\text{for all $E\in\Sigma, i_D^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma_D$.} $

It's immediate from the definitions that $i_D\colon (D,\Sigma_D)\to (X,\Sigma)$ is measurable, because $i_D^{-1}(E) = E\cap D$.

Suppose now that M is $\sigma$-algebra $M$ on $D$ such that $i_D\colon (D,M)\to (X,\Sigma)$ is measurable. Then for every $E\in\Sigma, $ we have $i_D^{-1}(E) = E\cap D \in M$. Thus $\Sigma_D\subseteq M$.

---

A concrete example: Suppose $X = \Bbb N$, $\Sigma = \mathcal{P}(X)$, and $D = $ the even integers. Do you see that $\Sigma_D = \{E\cap D\mid E\in \mathcal{P}(X)\} = \mathcal{P}(D)$?

Comment: What is the definition of a Borel $\sigma$ ALgebra?

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is the least $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$. Equivalently, it's the $\sigma$-algebra *generated* by $\tau$.

Comment: What about on a measure space?

Comment: What are you asking? A measure space comes with a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: This is where I am confused. Either something is in ∑ or it is not. If you have two things, one in their and one not then how can they intersect?

Comment: I gave you an example at the end of my answer. It seems pretty clear how they can intersect. I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @BrianO  is it true that integral of measurable function $f$ over measurable subset $D$ is equal to integral over $f$ restricted to $D$ when $D$ considered as subspace of measure space.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps too short for an answer, but the intuition behind it, is that you want to focus on $D$, so you cut everything else off, and you keep only everything's part in $D$, i.e $D\cap E$ for all $E$'s.

Comment: How can D and E intersect? Because D is in X and E is in a sigma algebra. Or is D also in that Sigma algebra?

Comment: Yes, $D$ and $X$ themselves are also in that $σ$-algebra.

Comment: So the definition could be modified as $\sigma_D =\{E \cap D: E,D \in \sum\}$?

Comment: No, wait. $D$ is fixed.

Comment: This is where I am confused, either something is in $\sum$ or it is not. If you have two things, one in their and one not then how can they intersect?

Comment: @Stef Beat me to it: yes, $D$ is fixed (a clue is that it's a subscript). By the way $\{E\cap D\mid E,D\in\Sigma\}$ is just $\Sigma$ :)

Comment: @BrianO you win...